# Is there an API that G-Suite / Gmail offers to retrieve emails from a Collaborative-inbox?

Tags: gmail-api

Using the [messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) API, am able to get emails from an individual user's mailbox. However, I have a need to fetch emails from a collaborative-inbox as well, for which am unable to find suitable API documentation.

Is this something possible? Is there a Gmail API that facilitates this?
Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by  collaborative-inbox?  Who ever owns it will need to authenticate your application.   Unless this is a gsuite account in which case you could use a service account with domain wide deligation set up

Comment: Collaborative-inbox is a type of [group](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430?hl=en).

Comment: I am using a service account with domain wide delegation, below are the scopes I tried with, to get messages from my collaborative-inbox group, but had no luck:

https://mail.google.com/,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/groups,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly

Pls lemme know if any needed scope left out.